# How to start a Cloud Foundry app via REST

Tags: cloud-foundry

What's the REST equivalent of the CLI command [`start APP`](http://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/start.html)?

I've tried using the API for [Creating an App](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/263/apps/creating_an_app.html), with the parameter `state` set to `STARTED`, and although that creates the app with a **requested state** of `started`, the app itself isn't running (the number of instances is `0` instead of `1`).

**Additional info:**

- In the App Creation request, I'm using the `docker_image` parameter to specify a certain Docker image containing the app.
- After making the request, if I try to start the app from the CLI I get an error: `App test is already started`, but as mentioned above, it obviously hasn't started. However, if I first call `cf stop test` and then `cf start test`, the app finally starts.

Answer (score 1):

There is not always a one-to-one mapping of cf cli commands to REST commands.  Often cf cli commands are compromised of multiple REST API calls.

The easiest way to see what the cli is doing for your particular situation is to run `CF_TRACE=true cf <command>`.  This will dump the HTTP requests that are sent for the command that you're running.  You can then mimic those in your application.

You can alternatively run `CF_TRACE=path/to/file.log cf <command>` and it will dump the HTTP request and responses to the file you indicate.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the update app cloudfoundry api and change the state of the app to "STARTED".

https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/263/apps/updating_an_app.html

curl "https://api.[your-domain.com]/v2/apps/ddd7e3cd-1b2e-4154-a109-0b4e7ba14447" -d '{
  "state": "STARTED","console": true
}' -X PUT \
    -H "Authorization: bearer token" \
    -H "Host: example.org" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    -H "Cookie: "